# Как вставить текст посередине границы блока?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Как сделать подобное?

[image]

Есть идея использовать рамку как `background-image` и поверх писать текст на html.

Есть ли какие-то еще варианты?

Comment: Используйте `<fieldset>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этого можно добиться с помощью комбинации тегов [`<fieldset>`](https://webref.ru/html/fieldset) и [`<legend>`](https://webref.ru/html/legend):

```css
legend {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Заголовок</legend>
  Текст текст текст
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Только стоит обратить внимание, что выравнивание с помощью CSS не везде работает; например, в Firefox 46.0.1 на Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64-bit), также (на сколько мне не изменяет память в IE не работает) ... Тогда можно использовать атрибут `align` со значение `center`: https://jsfiddle.net/3fhspz12/; но тогда, в свою очередь, документ не пройдет валидацию: https://goo.gl/hGqR7N.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov, проверил в Edge, в IE 11 и во всех режимах эмуляции вплоть до 8-го IE. Везде работает. В Firefox на Ubuntu проверить не могу, но верю вам на слово

Answer (score 3):

Ну, думаю так.

html:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend align="center">Заголовок</legend>
    <p>Куча вашего текста</p> 
</fieldset>
```

css:

```
fieldset
{
    width: 910px;
    height: 294px;
}
legend
{
    padding-left: 40px; /* Свои значения */
    padding-right: 40px; /* Свои значения */
}
```

Ну и ваш текст и его стилистика внутри.

Comment: Мы с вами об одном решении подумали :). Только атрибут `align` уже давно устарел, лучше перенесите свойство в стили.

Comment: @VenZell, Да, знаю) Text-align сначала не туда написал :)

Answer (score 1):

Еще как вариант

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  background: url('http://zellox.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/best-nature-background-desktop.jpg') no-repeat center top;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.b{  
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 25px 0;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 25px auto;  
}
.b-inner{  
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-top: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.b-text{
  padding: 25px;
}
.b-title{
  position: absolute; top: -12px; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.b-title > span{
  position: relative;
  display: block;  
}
.b-title > span:before,
.b-title > span:after {    
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 3px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
}
.b-title > span:before {
    right: 0.5em;
    margin-left: -50%;
}
.b-title > span:after {
    left: 0.5em;
    margin-right: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
<div class="b-inner">
<h3 class="b-title"><span>title text</span></h3>
  <div class="b-text"> 
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="b">
<div class="b-inner">
<h3 class="b-title"><span>title text title text</span></h3>
  <div class="b-text"> 
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
  </div>
```